# Что означает double... в java

Tags: java

столкнулся с проблемой в использовании API сторонней библиотеки Timeseries. Для инициализации объекта требуется параметр с типом double... . Пытался гуглить (честно), не нашел информации. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это такое и как туда запихать коллекцию. И если не сложно, что означает from между именем конструктора и аргументами. Заранее благодарю всех ответивших.
[image: code]

Comment: 0. Брррррррррр... 1. Код надо добавлять текстом. 2. Такой imgur заблокирован.

Comment: Гуглить по "java varargs".

Comment: `double from` - один аргумент типа `double` с именем `from`. `double... from` - 0, 1 или больше аргументов типа `double` через запятую, доступ к которым внутри метода производится путем обращения как к массиву даблов.

Answer (score 3):

Аргумент метода типа `double...` означает, что таких `double`-ов может быть сколько угодно, а сам аргумент есть массив, который неявно создаётся во время исполнения. Например:

```
void doSomething(double... num) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
}
```

Этот метод можно вызвать так:

```
doSomething(2.5, 7.8, 1.3, 5.0);
```

и это будет равносильно вызову так:

```
doSomething(new double[] {2.5, 7.8, 1.3, 5.0});
```

Можно даже так:

```
doSomething();
```

что равносильно вызову так:

```
doSomething(new double[0]);
```

или так:

```
doSomething(new double[]{});
```

Такой синтаксис с троеточием можно использовать с любым типом. Но есть одно ограничение - такой аргумент обязан быть последним в списке аргументов метода. Иначе получите ошибку компиляции.